# Differently styled HTML elements in browser's default css is the only factor for the different looks in different browser of website?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Differently styled HTML elements in all browser's default css is the only factor for the different looks in different browser of website?  **Which can be solved by reset css**

Can we achieve same look with CSS only?

Is there any other factors related to cross browser compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other factors related to cross browser compatibility?

Of course — browser bugs and quirks that aren’t addressed by web developers in their CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of factors, for example:

- Differences in the default styles (as you mentioned)
- Different set of installed fonts
- Different system settings for text smoothing
- Different settings for text size and zoom
- Varying support for standardised features (1)
- Varying support for non-standard features (2)
- Non-standard implementation of standards (bugs)
- Different strategies for dealing with errors in the code

(1) Different browsers support different standards up to a certain version, for example CSS 2.1. The standards targeted varies, and also there is often a few features missing from making the support 100% complete.

(2) Browsers support different features that are not yet standardized (or never will be). Especially Internet Explorer has a lot of non-standard features, which of course doesn't work in other browsers.

Comment: +1 thanks for good answer . can u pls give more details on #5 and #6

Answer (score 0):

you should check this [**principle of cross browser css**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/) you can find here and every browser have default setting when we doesn't define anything in our css than this occur like a bug or a error and our site look different in browser.

Comment: thx for reply this is not my question. my question is are there any other factors?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid of course reset css is also a part of css! and you can find all factor in link.